# Bootstrap carousel passing elements one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap with carousel to move the elements of a menu.

**I want to see 4 elements and pass one by one.**

With my code I have the effect: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39VBM/11/)**. (4 elements passing at time)

My code:

**JQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 10000
});
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
 <div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="item active">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">text 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">text 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">text 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">text 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">text 5</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">text 6</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-left: 11px;" >
        <a href="#" title="texto1"> <img
            src="http://musiccaptains.com/zh/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Account.png" class="center-block" 
            />
        </a>
        <p class="lead text-center" style="padding-top: 20px;">text 7</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Carousel is not a good way of doing this but you want to show the next and previous image.

Not mine but this kinda does what you want http://www.bootply.com/94444

Comment: Wouldn't be too sure, but to start I would use jquery and assign a number to each link and then pass in the numbers I want to be displayed in the div, 0-3 and then use the left and right arrows to increase and decrease that. Sorry I cant show you any examples don't have the time to work on it atm.